# If $\lambda a + \mu b = \alpha a + \beta b$ and $a$ and $b$ are not parallel, then $\lambda = \alpha$ and $\mu = \beta$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Going through my textbook, I've come across something I don't understand. it says, if $ \lambda a + \mu b = \alpha a + \beta b $ and the non-zero vectors **a** and **b** are not parallel, then $ \lambda = \alpha $ and $\mu = \beta$. Perhaps obvious, but to avoid ambiguity the greek letters are constants.

So, the reason I don't understand this is because I don't understand how in earth this even works...

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I've improved your title by making it more informative to other users. This will help potential answerers, as well as other people who may be confused. I have also added the tag [tag:linear-algebra] to better categorize this question. If you find yourself asking more questions in the future, then I encourage you to keep these improvements in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may know that two vectors are parallel if they are a multiple of one another; that is: (non-zero) vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are *parallel* if (and only if) there's a number $k \ne 0$ such that $\mathbf{a}=k\mathbf{b}$.

Now, in your case:
$$\lambda \mathbf{a} + \mu \mathbf{b} = \alpha \mathbf{a} + \beta \mathbf{b} \iff \left(\lambda-\alpha\right) \mathbf{a} = \left( \beta - \mu \right)\mathbf{b}$$
**Hint**: the right-hand side now seems to imply that $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are parallel, unless...

Comment: unless they equal zero. Understood thanks

Comment: Correct! You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We that
$$\lambda a+\mu b=\alpha a+\beta b$$
Thus,
$$(\lambda -\alpha) a+(\mu -\beta)b=0$$
Since $a$ and $b$ are not parallels (linearly independent) , the equality above is true only inte case $\lambda-\alpha=\mu-\beta$. Therefore,
$$\lambda=\alpha\quad\mbox{and}\quad\mu=\beta$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite the equality as
$$ \lambda a - \alpha a = \beta b - \mu b$$
or rather as
$$ (\lambda - \alpha)a = (\beta - \mu)b.$$
If $\lambda - \alpha \neq 0$, then this states that
$$ a = \frac{\beta - \mu}{\lambda - \alpha} b,$$
which means that the two vectors are multiples of each other. This is equivalent to $a$ being parallel to $b$. But we know this isn't true!

So $\lambda - \alpha = 0$, i.e. $\lambda = \alpha$. And thus $\beta = \mu$ as well.